# How to put a retuned array into another returned array?

Tags: php, arrays, testing

I have two files which return two arrays.

First:

```
<?php
return [
    "cats" => [
        [
            'id' => 1,
            "title" => 'qwer',
        ],
        [
            'id' => 2,
            "title" => 'asdf',
        ]
    ]
]
```

Second:

```
<?php
return [
    "fixtures" => [
            include "file1.php",
            "dogs" => [
                [
                    'id' => 1,
                    "title" => 'qwer',
                ],
            ],
            "pigs" => [
                [
                    'id' => 1,
                    "title" => 'qwer',
                ],
            ],
        ]
]
```

The array from first file must be putted into array in second file.
But if I do this by `include` it puts file1.php with outside brackets and I get this:

```
<?php
return [
    "fixtures" => [
            [
                 "cats" => [
                         [
                             'id' => 1,
                             "title" => 'qwer',
                         ],
                         [
                             'id' => 2,
                             "title" => 'asdf',
                         ]
                  ]
            ],
            "dogs" => [
                [
                    'id' => 1,
                    "title" => 'qwer',
                ],
            ],
            "pigs" => [
                [
                    'id' => 1,
                    "title" => 'qwer',
                ],
            ],
        ]
]
```

How can I put array from file1 without these outside brackets?

Comment: How should your result look like?

Answer (score 2):

You would have to merge the included data into the main array (`array_merge()`), the easiest way is to create the existing data and then add in the included data...

```
$c= [
    "fixtures" => [
        "dogs" => [
            [
                'id' => 1,
                "title" => 'qwer',
            ],
        ],
        "pigs" => [
            [
                'id' => 1,
                "title" => 'qwer',
            ],
        ],
    ]
];

$c['fixtures'] = array_merge($c['fixtures'], include "abc.php");

return $c;
```

Comment: But is it possible to do this directly inside returning array? To don't change currently structure of files

Comment: You can't do it directly unless you change the structure of the include slightly.

Answer (score 0):

I think, that this syntax with include will not work properly - may work now, but is very difficult to check if any errors in arrays. You must use `array_merge`. I think, that animals must be together:

```
$array1 = include('file0.php');
$array2 = include('file1.php');
if (is_array($array1) && is_array($array2)) {
  $array1['fixtures'] = array_merge($array1['fixtures'], $array2);
}
```